# How to retrieve frequencies of the number of unique occurrences of pair letters for every possible pair of columns from a numpy matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have a matrix like this using numpy matrix:

```
>>> print matrix
[['L' 'G' 'T' 'G' 'A' 'P' 'V' 'I']
 ['A' 'A' 'S' 'G' 'P' 'S' 'S' 'G']
 ['A' 'A' 'S' 'G' 'P' 'S' 'S' 'G']
 ['G' 'L' 'T' 'G' 'A' 'P' 'V' 'I']]
```

What I would like to have is FOR EVERY POSSIBLE pair of columns, retrieve the frequency of the number of unique occurrences of every pair of letters from the row within each pair of columns.

For instance, for the first pair column, that is:

```
[['L' 'G']
 ['A' 'A']
 ['A' 'A']
 ['G' 'L']]
```

I would like to retrieve the frequency of every pair of letters within the column (NOTE: the order of letters matters)

> Frequency of ['L' 'G'] = 1/4
>
> Frequency of ['A' 'A'] = 2/4
>
> Frequency of ['G' 'L'] = 1/4

Once these frequencies of the first pair column are calculated, then do the same for every other possible pair of columns combination.

I think some kind of itertools would help to solve this question, but I don't know how to... any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the number of items in a column always even?

Comment: no, could be odd as well

Comment: Are you talking about only _adjacent_ pairs or do you literally mean "every other possible pair of columns" -- i.e. column 1 and 5, column 1 and 6, column 2 and 4, and so on.

Comment: I mean every other possible pair of columns, NOT only adjacent pairs

Comment: Is the number of letters finite? How many?

Comment: yes, always one letter/character per matrix[i][j] position

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.combinations` and `collections.Counter`:

```
for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(s.T)), 2):
    c = s[:, [i,j]]
    counts = collections.Counter(map(tuple,c))
    print 'columns {} and {}'.format(i,j)
    for k in sorted(counts):
        print 'Frequency of {} = {}/{}'.format(k, counts[k], len(c))
    print
```

produces

```
columns 0 and 1
Frequency of ('A', 'A') = 2/4
Frequency of ('G', 'L') = 1/4
Frequency of ('L', 'G') = 1/4

columns 0 and 2
Frequency of ('A', 'S') = 2/4
Frequency of ('G', 'T') = 1/4
Frequency of ('L', 'T') = 1/4

[...]
```

(Modifying it to do both columns 0 1 and 1 0 if you want both orders is trivial, and I've assumed by every possible pair of columns you don't mean "every *adjacent* pair of columns").

Comment: when running your code this error is displayed: NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined... do you know why?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  `s` is the matrix, and `s.T` is its transpose.  I could have used `range(s.shape[1])` instead.

Comment: @ÀngelBa: `itertools` and `collections` are modules, like `numpy`.  You need to import them.  Add `import itertools, collections` before the code.

Comment: thanks @DSM One more question.. I forgot to ask for two other parameters, the individual frequency for both two letters (A and B for instance) within the columns... to finally have this: freq(A,B)/(freq(A)*freq(B))... maybe I should ask this in another question

Answer (score 0):

If you have memory to spare, for some sizes of your array, I am guessing few columns and many rows, it may pay off to do a more numpy intensive solution:

```
>>> rows, cols = matrix.shape
>>> matches = np.empty((rows, cols, cols, 2), dtype=str)
>>> matches[..., 0] = matrix[:, None, :]
>>> matches[..., 1] = matrix[:, :, None]
>>> matches = matches.view('S2')
>>> matches = matches.reshape((rows, cols, cols))
```

And now in `matches[:, i, j]` you have the unique pairs between columns `i` and `j`, and you can then do:

```
>>> unique, idx = np.unique(matches[:, 0, 1], return_inverse=True)
>>> counts = np.bincount(idx)
>>> unique
array(['AA', 'GL', 'LG'], 
      dtype='|S2')
>>> counts
array([2, 1, 1])
```